Supersplat Compressed .ply Support
I'm getting an unknown error when trying to import superplat compressed .ply files. Is there any way to do this? Some of these .plys compress to like 10% the size of a regular .ply.

There's no mention of compressed ply files in the Blender manual so presumably the importer doesn't support them.
